# Destructuring assignment vs array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new at ReactJs and have a question about this two method:

1:

```
handleLike = movie => {
  const movies = this.state.movies.map(m => {
    if (m._id === movie._id) m.liked = !m.liked;

    return m;
  });

  this.setState({ movies });
};
```

2:

```
handleLike = movie => {
  const movies = [...this.state.movies];
  const index = movies.indexOf(movie);
  movies[index] = { ...movies[index] };
  movies[index].liked = !movies[index].liked;

  this.setState({ movies });
};
```

Q1: This two methods just toggle *liked* and work properly but i want to know **there is any advantages** or not?

Q2: What is purpose of this line in second method:

```
  movies[index] = { ...movies[index] };
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use #1, at least not the way it is written. You are mutating the old state, which can easily cause bugs in react which assumes that state is immutable. You do create a new array, which is good, but you're not creating new elements inside the array. If you're changing one of the objects in the array, you need to copy that object before modifying it.

The better way to do #1 would be:

```
handleLike = movie => {
  const movies = this.state.movies.map(m => {
    if (m._id === movie._id) {
      const copy = { ...m };
      copy.liked = !m.liked;
      return copy;
    }
    return m;
  });

  this.setState({ movies });
};
```

And that kind of gets to your question about #2 as well:

> Q2: What is purpose of this line in second method:
>    `movies[index] = { ...movies[index] };`

The purpose of that is to make a copy of the movie. This lets you make a change to the copy, without modifying the old state.

> Q1: This two methods just toggle liked and work properly but i want to know there is any advantages or not?

If you fix the mutation issue in #1, then it's pretty much a matter of preference.